# Centos Node, nothing happen

Tags: node.js, centos

I installed `nodejs` and `npm` in CentOs 6.9 server.

I was trying to run command: `node bin/www` but nothing happened.

```
[root@server apprtc-node-server]# node bin/www
```

Please help me.

Comment: can you share the commands you used to install node on centos?

Comment: wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.30/node-v0.10.30.tar.gz
tar xzvf node-v* && cd node-v*


./configure
make

sudo make install

node --version
v0.10.30

Comment: You should explain your desired behavior and show the error/output of your command.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a .js file to the node command to be able to run it.